# Regex not working for correct input

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a regex for comma separated alphabets allowing trailing comma and space,

```
var rgx = /^[a-z\sA-Z]+(,[a-z\sA-Z]+)*,\s$/;
    return rgx.test(inputStr);
```

when i give two or more spaces after that it fails

```
name, fname lname,
```

when i correct the input which matches the regex, it is also failed.

```
name, fname lname,
```

so basically whenever regex is failed then even i correct the input, regex is not matching the input and i'm not allowed to move further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
,\s$
```

matches exactly one space after a comma before the end of input.  Two spaces at the end will cause it to fail.

To fix that, try

```
/^[a-z\sA-Z]+(,[a-z\sA-Z]+)*,\s+$/
```

If you want the comma and space at the end to be optional, try

```
/^[a-z\sA-Z]+(,[a-z\sA-Z]+)*(?:,\s*)?$/
```

I'm a little unclear what you're trying to do here though.

This regex doesn't do much except disallow commas at the start and adjacent to one another.

Comment: Thank you @Mike, but my problem here is that regex is working whenever i give undesired input, but once a wrong input is given then even after i correct the input according to the regex its always failing.

in short :- Once Failed, always failed  until i reload the window

Comment: @rohitj, Can you provide a short runnable example?

Comment: this(/^[a-z\sA-Z]+(,[a-z\sA-Z]+)*(?:,\s*)?$/) regex worked

Can you explain the difference b/w yours regex and mine. I'm not clear what portion was not working with mine and now working with your regex..

and Thanks a lot @Mike for the solution...